# jQuery get elements without display="none"

Tags: jquery, attributes, coding-style

How can I get all `tbody > tr` that doesn't have this style attribute: `display: none`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
$("tbody > tr:visible")
```

Should do it, by using the [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector.

Comment: just aware that this will be filtered out all the invisible elements which can be hidden by parent elements display:none styles.

Comment: Doesn't work with `option` elements with jQuery 3.6.0 : `$('option:visible', '#some-select-id')` returns an empty array on Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 38):

The accepted answer works, and is very useful, but not technically what the OP directly asked.

I'm splitting hairs, admittedly, but I needed to find only `tr` elements which literally did not contain `display: none` within their `style` attribute, because the parent element might be hidden, thus returning no elements.

So I wrote the following:

```
var $trWithoutDisplayNone = $('tbody > tr:not([style*="display: none"])');
```

---

Update:

The original code will select an array of *all* `tr`s on a page with no style attribute containing `"display: none"`.

A more efficient and specific way would be to target the table itself.

HTML:

```
<table id="tableID">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background: grey; display: none;">
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
<script>
    function getDisplayedRows($targetTable) {
            return $targetTable.find('tr:not([style*="display: none"])');
    }

    $(function() { //shortcut for document ready
        var $table = $("#tableID"), //get table by selector
            $visibleRows = getDisplayedRows($table); //run function to get rows without display: none
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. 
other one is filtered out all the invisible elements which can be hidden by parent elements display:none styles.