# How would you dynamically add another table if the previous one exceeds a certain height? (images provided)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, asp.net

**The images do my question more justice than my explanation.**

But I want to add another table after the height of the table prior exceeds a certain HEIGHT not a certain amount of rows.

> This is not for a WEBSITE. It's to use HTML to generate tables for a certification spreadsheet to print out as a PDF. Sorry for the poor explanation.

[image: BEFORE]
[image: AFTER]

Comment: Then how are you measuring height?

Comment: Here's a good example of row count change on a table. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776240/listening-for-table-rows-count-change

Comment: height isn't really a thing on the web since browsers just scroll as needed.
About the only accurate way is use CSS to set a max height for your result rows, then end/start a new table when X results have displayed

Comment: Adding another table with the same columns will most likely result in columns not being perfectly aligned in all browsers. No matter how I look at this, I don't see how someone could ever convince me this has the potential of adding extra value to user experience.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu it's to create a certification layout for potential employees at the company I work for. Using HTML to design it, and saving the web page as a PDF to print.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I explained this extremely poorly, I know... the TABLE would have a maximum height, but each row would be able to handle two to three lines of text.

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve the intended result, you should use print units for your elements: `em`, `cm`, `mm`, `in`, `pt`, `pc` & `%` for print layout and screen units `em`, `px`, `%` & `rem` for screen layout.

Full documentation [`here`](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html).

You could (and should) express specific display rules and units for each media type in appropriate media queries:

```
 @media print {
   /* print rules and units here */ 
 }

 @media screen { 
   /* screen rules and units here */ 
 }
```

With the above tools you can control the pagination of your form elements on print media without having to create unnecessary breaks in the screen layout.

I understand from your comments you are displaying forms. My recommendation is not to use `<table>` elements for layout (unless you are displaying tabular data).

Comment: Yes I completely agree regarding using <table> elements unless displaying tabular data, which is the case for this. I appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: @johndev you can wrap your "pages" in some `<div>`s that do not do anything in `screen` but on `print` they make a nice border and set the size of the elements. This is how print from web is done normally.